# onCameraIdleListener equivalent in Android v10 SDK

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-android

I have an expensive operation I want to run only when the camera is idle.  I am using the Mapbox v10-rc.5 SDK on Android.  With the Google Maps SDK, I can set up an `onCameraIdleListener`, and I see that there was a similar thing in previous versions of the Mapbox SDK.  How can I do this in v10?

I tried calling `addCameraAnimationsLifecycleListener` and responding in `onAnimatorEnding`, but this seems to trigger every frame when the user is doing pinch-to-zoom.  I tried checking `isGestureInProgress` or `isUserAnimationInProgress`, but they are either always or never true in this case (I forget which).  I see there is also `addMapIdleListener`, but it looks like that triggers when all the tiles are loaded, which is not what I want.